# How do I make my glasses look realistic?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, lighting, glass, reflection

I've been stuck for quite a while, it just looks wrong you can surely tell. I'm kinda new to blender, here's a picture:

[image]

**Q:** How can I improve the glass shader?

Comment: maybe share your file (at least a part of it) so that we can see what your nodes organization looks like and how it can be improved: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/   other than that there must be a lot of tutorial on how to create a glass material

Answer (score 1):

You can have a basic glass material if you mix these 3 nodes: *Glass*, *Glossy* and *Transparent*. For example this seems to work fine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this node setup to get realistic glass shader in cycles...

[image]

If you add in just a glass shader, blender will try to calculate all the caustics which in turn will fill you scene with a lot of noise.The node setup I have mentioned will fake the object as a transparent yet shining surface..

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Can you explain your choices for the lightpath? why such value for fresnel?

Comment: This worked great. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Just use the principled shader, set the transmission to 1, roughness and transmission roughness to 0 and make the base color pure white

Answer (score -2):

You can select the mesh of the glass and give it a Glass BSDF material. Changing the roughness value in the properties should give you the amount of transparency you want.

No Nodes Necessary.